# How can I fix the position of the first keyframe while scaling all others?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

I have this code that scales all keyframes by half.

[image]

But the problem is that it also scales the first keyframe and moves it near zero.

[image]

I want to mimic the scaling of keyframes in the viewport editor where the first keyframe is fixed and all others scale by a specific number. Is there a way I can achieve that?

```
import bpy

# get the active object
obj = bpy.context.active_object
# get the animation data and fcurves from the object
# the fcurves are a good way to get direct access to the keyframes
curves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves

#loop over every fcurve
for c in curves:
    # get the keyframes for every fcurve
    keyframes = c.keyframe_points
    #loop over every keyframe and divide their x coordinate by a scale factor
    for kf in keyframes:
        #this is the number to scale by, 
        #if  you want to scale them all down by half then you'd divide by two
        scale_factor = 2.0
        # co is the keyframe's coordinate attribute
        # we only want to scale them on the x-axis (time) 
        # not on the y (amplitude)
        # /= is a shorthand for saying kf.co.x = kf.co.x / 2
        kf.co.x /= scale_factor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
import bpy

# get the active object
obj = bpy.context.active_object
# get the animation data and fcurves from the object
# the fcurves are a good way to get direct access to the keyframes
curves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves

# loop over every fcurve
for c in curves:
    # get the keyframes for every fcurve
    keyframes = c.keyframe_points
    # loop over every keyframe starting from the second one
    for i in range(1, len(keyframes)):
        kf = keyframes[i]
        # this is the number to scale by,
        # if you want to scale them all down by half then you'd divide by two
        scale_factor = 2.0
        # co is the keyframe's coordinate attribute
        # we only want to scale them on the x-axis (time)
        # not on the y (amplitude)
        # /= is a shorthand for saying kf.co.x = kf.co.x / scale_factor
        kf.co.x /= scale_factor

```
````

Comment: This approach may induce errors if the initial key is not at 0. For instance if initial key is at frame 4 and the next key is at frame 6 ideally your scale should reflect the delta of the initial key to the next key instead of simply dividing its value.